# Error after Angular update from v9 to v10. Property 'propertyName' is used before its initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-upgrade

I searched in Google/Github/Stackoverflow about this error but I am not able to fix this.
I hope someone can help with a fix or suggestion

I have updated Angular project from v9 to v10, and after the update i got errors like the followwing, in a couple of modules.

> Property 'searchParameters' is used before its initialization.

> address: this.searchParameters?.address,

And the code in short:

```
export interface PartnerSearchParameters {
   name?: string;
   code?: string;
   address?: string;
   taxRegNumber?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-partner-search-list',
  templateUrl: './partner-search-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partner-search-list.component.scss']
})

export class PartnerSearchListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

searchParameters: PartnerSearchParameters;

modelMainFilters = {
    address: this.searchParameters?.address,
    code: this.searchParameters?.code,
    name: this.searchParameters?.name 
    taxRegNumber: this.searchParameters?.taxRegNumber ,
  };

constructor(...){}
ngOnInit(): void {...}
...
}
```

The searchParameters is defined before the modelMainFilters, where i want to use ..

So I don’t understand at all where I should define it to be good.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, properties of `searchParameters` are attempted to be used before it's initialized.

One solution is to initialize it with some values

```js
searchParameters: PartnerSearchParameters = {
  name: '',
  code: '',
  address: '',
  taxRegNumber: ''
}
```

Or better yet, initialize the `modelMainFilters` only after the `searchParameters` are initialized

```js
export class PartnerSearchListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  searchParameters: PartnerSearchParameters;
  modelMainFilters: PartnerSearchParameters;

  ngOnInit(): {
    this.someFunc().subscribe(res => {       // <-- example
      this.searchParameters = res;
      this.modelMainFilters = this.searchParameters;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) like this:

```
export interface PartnerSearchParameters {
   name?: string;
   code?: string;
   address?: string;
   taxRegNumber?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-partner-search-list',
  templateUrl: './partner-search-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partner-search-list.component.scss']
})

export class PartnerSearchListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

searchParameters!: PartnerSearchParameters;

modelMainFilters = {
    address: this.searchParameters?.address,
    code: this.searchParameters?.code,
    name: this.searchParameters?.name, 
    taxRegNumber: this.searchParameters?.taxRegNumber
  };

constructor(...){}
ngOnInit(): void {...}
...
}
```

Keep in mind doing this you will end up with all properties of `modelMainFilters` equal to `undefined` like this:

```
modelMainFilters: {
  address: undefined,
  code: undefined,
  name: undefined,
  taxRegNumber: undefined
}
```